# how to clear all jTextField in for loop?

Tags: java

i have 30 jtextfield: jTextField1..through..jTextField30  ; to avoid redundancy i'm trying to clear all fields in for loop such that:

```
          for (int i=1;i<31;i++)
                {
                    jTextField(String.valueOf(i)).setText("")

                }
```

but it is error in this way , how to do it ?

Comment: Do you have an `array` or `arraylist` of `JTextFields` anywhere?

Comment: @3Kings No ...have an idea ??

Comment: what are you trying to do with  `jTextField(what?).setText("")`

Comment: You either need to have an array/arrayList of all the JTextField  and run through them all to clear

Comment: @3Kings to clear all fields when i click a button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need something like this

```
ArrayList<JTextField> fields = new ArrayList<JTextField>(); //This needs to be populated with your JTextFields
for(int i = 0; i < fields.size(); i++)
    if(fields.get(i) != null)
        fields.get(i).setText("");
```